# Australian student visa rejected because of GTE. Will it affect New Zealand student visa?

Tags: immigration, student-visa, new-zealand

My Australian student visa was rejected on GTE (Genuine Temporary Entrant) grounds. Will it affect a New Zealand student visa?

Also, do I need to declare that I have had a previous student visa rejection? What if I don't?

Comment: Okk I ll mention the about the rejection.So according to you if I select different course and mention effective reasons in my SOP and show strong incentive Of coming back;any chances of visa?

Answer (score 3):

Like the Big5/eyes agreement between USA, UK, Australia, Canada and France (?), Australia and New Zealand may also have some kind of immigration data sharing agreement, most likely, because they are neighbors, but at same time Big5/eye concentrates more on security risks.

If New Zealand's (or for that matter, any country's) visa form asks for previous rejections/deportations/refusals, it is never a good idea to lie. State the facts, because caught lieing may open another can of immigration problems, and will, most probably.

TL:DR; Aussie refusal may effect Kiwi application outcome, Never lie on immigration forms.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare any rejections and application.  If you do not, it will undoubtedly be counted against you. The government officials will not overlook dishonesty.

I can tell you, before entering the country, they will have you sit off to the side or in a secure location and check your information if your visa is flagged. I was asked to sit in an area for 1 1/2 hours after I visited my family in the US, at the time I had a spousal visa. Even though I had a valid spousal visa, my file showed I had previously been rejected my first spousal visa application as the law changed at the time I applied while i had a valid student visa. While waiting in the area, they spoke with my husband who was waiting for me on the other side to check out the validity of my statements.

I can only implore you be completely honest.

Answer (score -4):

Australia and NZ have very similar visa assessment approach. From a risk management approach:

- If you think NZ will reject your visa since they require similar condition
  to Australia, definitely don't mention it. It is worth being caught
  and still they will give you a chance to say why you lied and you can tell I was afraid to be rejected.
  If you think NZ entry is easier than Australia and your circumstances have changed and you can prove better situation maybe it is not worth taking the risk.

By the way the simple answer is yes. It will definitely raise their concern why you were rejected. Again, if you have many families in Australia, they may consider you are not going to stay in NZ.

Comment: If you lie, and when caught say that you lied because you thought it would improve the chance that your application would be accepted, you will certainly not be going to New Zealand for a long time.